# How to match regions in difference in difference analysis

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I've had an idea for a project to work on over Winter break. It involves a difference in difference analysis of two similar-sized cities on different sides of a state border. How do I confirm that the two cities are similar enough in their characteristics? Is it an eye test or is there a statistical methodology?

I would also appreciate any suggested readings.

Comment: Do you have ~4 data points (pre and post for two cities), or is your data at a lower level of aggregation, like people or neighborhoods nested in cities?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I have pre and post data

Comment: There’s is no way to do statistics with 4 data points per variable. At best, you can just show the raw data in the table. The same goes for the DID.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov sorry for the confusion, I have about 500 observations split about evenly before and after for both regions-- not 4

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the means of the features of the cities to see if they are balanced.Or you can look at the time-trends in their features (trends should be similar).